# iphone development: when I analyze my app I have potential leak issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, cgimageref

When I analyze my iPhone app I have a blue arrow warning which says:

```
potential leak of an object stored into pauseImgBg
```

I simply crop a partial image from an atlas and put it into the `pauseMenuIV` `imageView`.

```
CGImageRef pauseImgBg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([UIImage imageNamed:@"atlas.png"].CGImage, CGRectMake(1, 1, 640.0f, 960.0f));
pauseMenu = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:pauseImgBg])];// I have the blue arrow in this line
[pauseMenuIV setImage:pauseMenu];
```

What could be the problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` returns a CGImageRef with a retain count of +1. So you must release the recevied CGImageRef.

```
CGImageRelease(pauseImgBg);
```

in the end. Try and read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html) when you have the time. It will help you to isolate these kinds of cases. From documentation

> Core Foundation functions have names that indicate when you own a
>   returned object:
>
> - Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name
> - Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name.
>
> If you own an object, it is your responsibility to relinquish
>   ownership when you have finished with it.

And from the documentation of [CGImageCreateWithImageInRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) itself

> The resulting image retains a reference to the original image, which
>   means you may release the original image after calling this function.

Answer (score 3):

you'll probably need to release it  via

```
CGImageRelease(pauseImgBg);
```

Comment: even im using ARC also need to release it manually? @AppleDelegate